Node-Red Linux minimalist rootfs risc based how-to arecord live microphone audio stream to udp or tcp stdout stream to open broadcast studio
I have node-red on linux minimalist rootfs risc based, meaning I cannot install alsa, alsa-utils, ffmpeg, gstreamer, etc.
The linux device does have embedded sound card microphone hw:0,0 and speaker hw:1,0 , node-red, node-red-contrib-sscma, node-red-contrib-mic, node-red-contrib-sox-utils (without alsa), node-red-node-ui-microphone, node-red-contrib-wav, node-red-contrib-play-audio.
I've reviewed tons of online forums, stackoverflow, and others for learn how-to, clues, and examples to no avail. The Node-Red code 1, 2, and 3 are listed below. Some are new, while others are expanded ideas and trials, etc.
I am trying to perform Live Microphone arecord stream to either the UDP STDOUT or TCP STDOUT and using Open Broadcast Studio for Media audio listen at udp or tcp://192.168.1.202:defined port as per Node-Red flow enabled.
I've tried several node.js scripts, but it is challenging to work with linux minimalist risc based whereby many technologies are not compatible for this platform and encountering many node.js errors, and so the focus is node-red integration.
Note, for this linux risc device is on private network and so, be warned the Exec node client sudo call is a security risk (however, no real security risk for private network) as in this is required for arecord execution unless someone can provide feedback of how to adjust security in terminal for revising Node-Red Exec arecord call without client sudo is greatly appreciated, and be sure to replace your "password" in the Exec arecord node:
echo "password" | sudo -S -k  /usr/bin/arecord -D hw:0,0 -t wav -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 16000 --buffer-size 4096 -B 49152
Note 1: The above arecord may/will likely generate error: Err Client Process Stdio Max Buffer condition, any clues for resolving this is greatly appreciated.
Note 2: The above arecord is "when command is complete - exec mode", it does not work "when command is complete - spawn mode', unless unknown if perhaps the client sudo call is removed ?
Optional 1: Node.js can be added if example is provided using Node-Red Exec node to the path of home device: /home/device-user or home device .node-red: /home/device-user/.node-red
Optional 2: Also will consider using the following nodes, but I haven't seen any online posts or clues for these, and I can certainly try them: 'http in', 'http response', 'http request', 'websocket in', 'websocket out'.
Optional 3: If arecord stream/buffer can be better utilized for local disk file name based method such as "output.wav" or "output.raw" and aplay for reading this to UDP or TCP Stdio will be considered as in "real time" streaming with < 1 second delay or less.
Thanks all whom reads and contributes toward the solution is greatly appreciated.
Node-Red code 1:
[
{
    "id": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 8",
    "disabled": false,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "a8b78d1575e6a10d",
    "type": "sox-record",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "buttonStart": "msg",
    "inputs": 1,
    "inputSource": "fromInput",
    "manualSource": "mic arecord",
    "inputEncoding": "signed-integer",
    "inputChannels": 1,
    "inputRate": 16000,
    "inputBits": 16,
    "byteOrder": "-L",
    "encoding": "signed-integer",
    "channels": 1,
    "rate": 16000,
    "bits": 16,
    "gain": "20",
    "buffer": "4096",
    "showDuration": true,
    "durationType": "forever",
    "durationLength": "0",
    "silenceDetection": "nothing",
    "silenceDuration": "2.0",
    "silenceThreshold": "2.0",
    "outputFormat": "stream",
    "manualPath": "",
    "debugOutput": true,
    "x": 390,
    "y": 220,
    "wires": [
        [
            "f975679378b65881",
            "e9d29ebc8db093f2"
        ],
        [
            "6cd8b20ae32fb25a"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "6cd8b20ae32fb25a",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "debug 10",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 460,
    "y": 320,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "f975679378b65881",
    "type": "sox-play",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "outputDevice": "default",
    "manualOutput": "",
    "gain": "20",
    "startNew": "queue",
    "playStream": false,
    "inputEncoding": "signed-integer",
    "inputChannels": 1,
    "inputRate": 16000,
    "inputBits": 16,
    "debugOutput": true,
    "x": 540,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "463fd86ace3aaa10",
            "48273621d460d93e",
            "d02eabe332d47843"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "463fd86ace3aaa10",
    "type": "play audio",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "voice": "0",
    "x": 750,
    "y": 220,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "48273621d460d93e",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "debug 11",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 680,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "56151afb8dfddd80",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 100,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a1ecf44d565c6730",
            "ce091a5a5a83547c"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "a1ecf44d565c6730",
    "type": "exec",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "command": "echo \"password\" | sudo -S -k  /usr/bin/arecord -D hw:0,0 -t wav -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 16000 --buffer-size 4096 -B 49152",
    "addpay": "",
    "append": "",
    "useSpawn": "false",
    "timer": "",
    "winHide": false,
    "oldrc": false,
    "name": "mic arecord",
    "x": 290,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a8b78d1575e6a10d"
        ],
        [
            "216b3728886eda80"
        ],
        [
            "216b3728886eda80"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "b56609ace234dba3",
    "type": "tcp in",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "server": "server",
    "host": "",
    "port": "8090",
    "datamode": "stream",
    "datatype": "buffer",
    "newline": "",
    "topic": "",
    "trim": false,
    "base64": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 120,
    "y": 320,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a1ecf44d565c6730",
            "ce091a5a5a83547c"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "e9d29ebc8db093f2",
    "type": "tcp out",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "host": "",
    "port": "",
    "beserver": "reply",
    "base64": false,
    "end": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 650,
    "y": 280,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "ce091a5a5a83547c",
    "type": "Mic",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "d": true,
    "name": "",
    "outputPayloadType": "buffer",
    "endian": "little",
    "bitwidth": "16",
    "encoding": "signed-integer",
    "channels": "1",
    "device": "hw:0,0",
    "rate": "16000",
    "silenceTimeout": 0,
    "exitOnSilence": "false",
    "debug": "true",
    "active": false,
    "x": 210,
    "y": 220,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a8b78d1575e6a10d",
            "3c9b7be17810f7f9"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "3c9b7be17810f7f9",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "debug 12",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 380,
    "y": 380,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "216b3728886eda80",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "debug 13",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 520,
    "y": 60,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "d02eabe332d47843",
    "type": "tcp out",
    "z": "fde30f947a18a3b7",
    "name": "",
    "host": "",
    "port": "",
    "beserver": "reply",
    "base64": false,
    "end": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 810,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": []
}

]
Node-Red code 2:
[
{
    "id": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 2",
    "disabled": true,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "a93e9698e5419cec",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "debug 3",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 760,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "a7893ce8bb30deab",
    "type": "udp out",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "d": true,
    "name": "",
    "addr": "192.168.1.202",
    "iface": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "8080",
    "ipv": "udp4",
    "outport": "",
    "base64": false,
    "multicast": "false",
    "x": 810,
    "y": 200,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "0830aa1ea2b2a189",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "debug 4",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "false",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 400,
    "y": 140,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "86a39cbd6eba34ac",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 130,
    "y": 100,
    "wires": [
        [
            "8e240603cebdaeab"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "5d02a8d7d42b251d",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "function 2",
    "func": "msg.payload = Buffer.from(msg.payload);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "timeout": 0,
    "noerr": 0,
    "initialize": "",
    "finalize": "",
    "libs": [],
    "x": 520,
    "y": 360,
    "wires": [
        [
            "a7893ce8bb30deab",
            "9704149016df9611",
            "d31c6cc514d803d0",
            "a93e9698e5419cec"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "8e240603cebdaeab",
    "type": "exec",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "command": "echo \"password\" | sudo -S -k  /usr/bin/arecord -D hw:0,0 -t wav -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 16000 --buffer-size 4096 -B 49152",
    "addpay": "",
    "append": "",
    "useSpawn": "false",
    "timer": "",
    "winHide": false,
    "oldrc": false,
    "name": "mic arecord",
    "x": 290,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": [
        [
            "0830aa1ea2b2a189",
            "5d02a8d7d42b251d",
            "d31c6cc514d803d0",
            "82dcef133b66f15e"
        ],
        [
            "0830aa1ea2b2a189"
        ],
        [
            "0830aa1ea2b2a189"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "11eeb3f6a3f5ca60",
    "type": "tcp in",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "d": true,
    "name": "",
    "server": "server",
    "host": "",
    "port": "8080",
    "datamode": "stream",
    "datatype": "buffer",
    "newline": "",
    "topic": "",
    "trim": false,
    "base64": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 100,
    "y": 320,
    "wires": [
        [
            "8e240603cebdaeab"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "d31c6cc514d803d0",
    "type": "tcp out",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "d": true,
    "name": "",
    "host": "",
    "port": "",
    "beserver": "reply",
    "base64": false,
    "end": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 770,
    "y": 280,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "c8ac267dadf14103",
    "type": "udp in",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "",
    "iface": "",
    "port": "8080",
    "ipv": "udp4",
    "multicast": "false",
    "group": "",
    "datatype": "buffer",
    "x": 100,
    "y": 200,
    "wires": [
        [
            "8e240603cebdaeab"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "9704149016df9611",
    "type": "udp out",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "",
    "addr": "192.168.1.3",
    "iface": "",
    "port": "8080",
    "ipv": "udp4",
    "outport": "8081",
    "base64": false,
    "multicast": "false",
    "x": 800,
    "y": 360,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "82dcef133b66f15e",
    "type": "play audio",
    "z": "c0a5f276e026d041",
    "name": "",
    "voice": "0",
    "x": 570,
    "y": 440,
    "wires": []
}

]
Node-Red code 3:
[
{
    "id": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "type": "tab",
    "label": "Flow 4",
    "disabled": true,
    "info": "",
    "env": []
},
{
    "id": "13128cf7473ff713",
    "type": "Mic",
    "z": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "name": "",
    "outputPayloadType": "stream",
    "endian": "little",
    "bitwidth": "16",
    "encoding": "signed-integer",
    "channels": "2",
    "device": "hw:0,0",
    "rate": "22050",
    "silenceTimeout": 0,
    "exitOnSilence": "false",
    "debug": "true",
    "active": false,
    "x": 370,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": [
        [
            "36ca5972d536e090",
            "1983fa1377741f50"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "bffa162978ef2250",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "name": "",
    "props": [
        {
            "p": "payload"
        },
        {
            "p": "topic",
            "vt": "str"
        }
    ],
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": false,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "x": 140,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": [
        [
            "13128cf7473ff713"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "466a6c52245501cf",
    "type": "tcp in",
    "z": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "name": "",
    "server": "server",
    "host": "",
    "port": "8080",
    "datamode": "stream",
    "datatype": "buffer",
    "newline": "",
    "topic": "",
    "trim": false,
    "base64": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 160,
    "y": 200,
    "wires": [
        [
            "13128cf7473ff713"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "1983fa1377741f50",
    "type": "tcp out",
    "z": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "name": "",
    "host": "",
    "port": "",
    "beserver": "reply",
    "base64": false,
    "end": false,
    "tls": "",
    "x": 750,
    "y": 160,
    "wires": []
},
{
    "id": "36ca5972d536e090",
    "type": "debug",
    "z": "1d6c3c87f9c03816",
    "name": "debug 6",
    "active": true,
    "tosidebar": true,
    "console": false,
    "tostatus": false,
    "complete": "payload",
    "targetType": "msg",
    "statusVal": "",
    "statusType": "auto",
    "x": 680,
    "y": 260,
    "wires": []
}

]

For a process that will not end like arecord then you should be using spawn mode

You should configure sudo to not require a password just for the arecord or better yet add the user running node-red to the right group to access the mike

@hardillb - meaning chown user:root /usr/bin/arecord ?
I've looked at sudo visudo, but it is not installed in this linux minimalist rootfs and it has sudoers.d with file sudo_users has user ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL ... and so, how would changing this help the solution for the above condition?

No, go read the sudo docs on how to mark specific commands as not needing a password (this is a super user question, not stack overflow) https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password
